# Vaadin and markdown

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I searched through the Vaadin documentation but couldn't find a way to render markdown.

Is there a widget allowing that ?

Or should I convert markdown into HTML ?

Comment: There is no component. So I would generate HTML. Do you only want to display it or also edit?

Comment: Both. I want to create a text editor and a way to render it. Markdown seemed appropriate to me

Comment: There is a RichTextEditor component but this commercial. Do you have pro subscription? For this you'll find an interesting discussion here https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/2017

Comment: I use Vaadin for my personal projects so a pro subscription is a little bit expensive for me. So no, I don't have a pro susbcription.

Comment: Then you could use TinyMCE https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-flow

Comment: Thanks a lots, I will take a look at that

Comment: Pick a mark down library, send the result through Jsoup's HTML sanitizer, and finally show the result using the Html class of Vaadin.

Answer (score 5):

See the [*Vaadin Directory*](https://vaadin.com/directory/search) of add-ons.

There you will find [*Markdown Area*](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/markdown-area) by [Maxime Rauturier](https://vaadin.com/directory/search?author=Maxime%20Rauturier), a simple `TextArea` to preview the markdown syntax. Works in Vaadin Flow, version 10+.

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.vaadin.maxime</groupId>
  <artifactId>markdown-area</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Searching the Directory [reveals several MarkDown](https://vaadin.com/directory/search?keyword=MarkDown) related items.